# Know if TResult is empty collection

Tags: c#, generics

I have this code

```
public static class FallbackUtils<TResult, TRequest>
      where TRequest : IFallbackRequest
   {
      public static IEnumerable<TResult> GetAllValues(TRequest request,
         Func<TRequest, TResult> callback)          
      {
         yield return callback(request);

         while (request.CanFallback())
         {
            request.Fallback();
            yield return callback(request);
         }
      }  
   }
```

Sometimes TResult is going to be an IEnumerable. In those cases I want to be able to keep not only null but empty collections from being returned. The problem is that I don't know how to ask TResult if it's empty I know only how to ask if it's null.
Something like this

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> GetAllValues(TRequest request,
         Func<TRequest, TResult> callback, bool ignoreNullOrEmpty = false)          
      {
         var item = callback(request);

         if (ignoreNullOrEmpty)
         {
            if (item != null && item.Any())
               yield return item;
         }
         else
            yield return item;

         while (request.CanFallback())
         {
            request.Fallback();

            item = callback(request);
            if (ignoreNullOrEmpty)
            {
               if (item != null && item.Any())
                  yield return item;
            }
            else
               yield return item;
         }
      }
```

I want to do the filtering inside this method to clean up a lot of duplicate code that is doing this same thing.

Any ideas of what should I do or what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there is no `Any` method on `IEnumerable`, you could write your own method:

```
public static bool Any(this IEnumerable source)
{
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

    return enumerator.MoveNext();
}
```

Then you can call it:

```
if (item != null && 
    item is IEnumerable && 
    ((IEnumerable)item).Any())
```

Comment: @Chorinator be warned, this will NOT work for an IEnumerable<T> since they're two different interfaces.

Comment: @Xcelled194 you are **wrong**. it will work for IEnumerable<T> because it inherits from IEnumerable.

Comment: Whoops, forgot about that.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to know if your `TResult` is `IEnumerable`, then you just need try to cast to it. Afterwards you can handle the empty collection and null values as follows:

```
// is it an IEnumerable?
var item = callback(request);
var enumerable = item as IEnumerable;
if(enumerable != null) 
{
  var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
  if(!enumerator.MoveNext())
  {
     // handle an empty collection here
  }
  else
  {
     do 
     {
        if(enumerator.Current == null)
          // handle the null value here
     } while(enumerator.MoveNext());
  }
}
```

Since you probably do not know the type of the items being inside the IEnumerable, you cannot use `IEnumerable<T>` and Linq extensions.

Comment: This is the best answer here.